# Keeping one li visible on bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, navbar

I have a standard navbar in bootstrap.  When it collapses, I see nothing but a hamburger menu button and all li's are folded underneath.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/store">Store</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

When it collapses (mobile/small screen) I would like for the "Store" link to stay visible at the top of the navbar, left of the Hamburger menu.  Can I do this using bootstrap's classes, or do I need to do this manually via `@media`?

Comment: You can use existing class from bootstrap for responsive utilities here is the link for it http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I got a solution. Try putting the button after

```
<div class="navbar-header">
```

and before

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ye7srbd/) is a JsFiddle. What I basically did:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" aria-label="Left Align" href="/store">
          Store
        </button>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/store">Store</a></li>
              <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Hope I could help you and my answer solved your problem. :)